# checking local email messages with Python

Tags: python, email

My problem is what's the best strategy for periodically checking a local email account to find if there is any new message(if any, then send these messages to some function to process)?

While during development, we use a Gmail account, so we use a periodic celery task to check the gmail account (through IMAP), and process the emails if there is any.

Now if we implement the mail server by ourselves, shall I still IMAP to the server, or I can just read the files under Maildir? Which is the preferred way?

Actually my problem may not be language-specific, but since I'm using Django/Python, so I just put it in the title. But a general answer about the pros and cons would be enough. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `mailbox` module:

http://docs.python.org/2/library/mailbox.html
http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/mailbox.html

It would be far faster to just read the messages directly than to interact via IMAP.